# How to delete data which is older than 30 minutes or 24 hours from mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete rows of data where the time when the data was inserted `Column is called Created` is older than 30 minutes or 24 hours older than the current time.

I have looked throughout this website and they keep on suggesting doing this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ytable WHERE Created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTES);",$db_con);
```

or something along those lines, but it never works.

Which part of the code is wrong. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a created column in your table? Or a created timestamp?

Comment: Can I assume you're using PHP as query agent to fetch/store data, since you placed a `php` tag? If so, why not use it to do such time test?

Comment: @shanehoban It is a column called 'Created' which is a time stamp which inserts the time when the row of data is inserted.

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki Great! Now, is that a timestamp created via MySQL, or is it a timestamp created in PHP?

Comment: @shanehoban created via MySQL. Does that matter?

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki Well no not really, it can likely be done either way. I find using PHP is much easier because it's just a long number, and it's really easy to see if one number is greater than another within a MySQL query (larger number meaning more recent). I avoid timestamps in MySQL for this reason. Some info on PHP time here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php. I generate a time in PHP and store that in the Database. If I want to get something within 24 hours for example, it's `current time - (60*60*24)`. Whatever is greater is within 24 hours

Comment: @shanehoban Then can you show me how to get the time in php when you insert the data itself and can you show me the whole code on how to delete rows of data which is older than 30 minutes. Then I will be sure to upvote it down below

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki I've added an answer, but I can't really go into as much detail as you've described because I don't know the inner workings of your code. The general outline I've provided should be enough to get you going

Comment: Working examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70449017/7186739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more informational than anything, perhaps may answer your question too. I'm trying to expand on my long comment above. This is just what I do. It is not the bible and personal preference prevails.

In your MySQL table, make the created an INTEGER, or even VARCHAR works too. Use PHP to generate the created at time (a long series of numbers from 1970). This is generated like so:

`$currentTime = time(); // e.g. 1439823230`

This is used during your `INSERT` queries, provided they are instigated through PHP too.

Now, you can also take into account timezones for this, but that will again depend on your preferences, and/or perhaps the server location.

Now when you have a large number of items in your Database, you can always create your own queries of lengths of time that you want to pull data from. For example:

```
$twentyFourHoursAgo = ($currentTime - 60*60*24);

#Example Query:
SELECT * FROM whatever_table WHERE created > $twentyFourHoursAgo
```

The above example will return everything within the last 24 hours. Multiply your times as needed. Also be sure to bind your parameters, and do not hard code them as shown in the above pseudo like example.

---

Here's a useful resource: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Specifically: http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension

Answer (score 1):

you could use DATE_SUB:

```
.. where Created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to remove the 'S' from MINUTES:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ytable WHERE Created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);",$db_con);
```

Comment: That did delete all of the data which was created 30 minutes ago, but it updated the time for the rows of data which was not deleted meaning if I tried to delete the data every 30 minutes, it will become a loop of the data not being deleted

Comment: Have you got another query running somewhere? This should simply do a delete, not a delete and update.

Comment: I've got the page updating every 30 minutes as well. This is because I want to take in new data as well as delete the old data. Any solutions?

Comment: Even with the page refreshing every 30 minutes, the query above shouldn't update the other times. Could you update your original post with the section of code your update query is in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70449017/7186739

Answer (score 0):

$time = date('YmdHis', time() - 1800);

$query = mysql_query($db_con, "DELETE FROM ytable WHERE date_time < '$time'");