# Delete 24 Hours older records in PHP using Mysql

Tags: mysql, intervals

Queries are working fine. I just want to know the role of the `INTERVAL` keyword in these queries

---

Delete 30 minutes older records using Mysql

```
DELETE FROM `token_tbl` WHERE `dateCreate` < (Now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Delete 1 Hour older records using Mysql

```
DELETE FROM `token_tbl` WHERE `dateCreate` < (Now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Delete 24 Hours older records using Mysql

```
DELETE FROM `token_tbl` WHERE `dateCreate` < (Now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval

Comment: It compare `dateCreate` with timestamp of 1 minute before. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interval` denotes a period of time. I.e., `Now() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` means "one minute before the current time". Then the condition would be any records that have `dateCreate` that are older than a minute ago.